# Summing random numbers in parallel

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, random

I am playing around with parallelization in Java and am trying to see how to squeeze out more performance on my multi-core box.  My machine has 6 physical cores, 12 with hyperthreading.

However, with this code, I only see performance improvements up to about 3-4 threads, after which the improvements top off and then decline. I would expect performance to decline beyond, let's say, 6-8 threads, but not before.  What, if anything, could I do to improve the code, especially with respect to improving speed?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class AddStuff 
{
   private static final int FIFTY_MILLION = 50000000;

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      final int numRecords = FIFTY_MILLION;
      final int numIterations = 100;
      final int maxThreads = 20;

      double[] numbers = new double[numRecords];
      Random r = new Random(1);

      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
         numbers[i] = r.nextDouble();

      System.out.println(String.format("Running aggregation of %d times %d iterations...", numRecords, numIterations));

      for (int numThreads = 1; numThreads <= maxThreads; numThreads++)
         runExperiment(numRecords, numIterations, numThreads, numbers);

      System.out.println("Done");      
   }

   private static void runExperiment(final int numRecords, final int numIterations, final int numThreads, double[] numbers) {

      long start = System.nanoTime();

      double total = 0;
      for (int iteration = 0; iteration < numIterations; iteration++)
         total +=computeTotal(numbers, numThreads);

      double duration = ((double) (System.nanoTime() - start)) / 1000000000;


      System.out.println(String.format("Threads: %d,  Time: %.4fs,  Total: %f ", numThreads, duration, total));
   }

   private static double computeTotal(double[] numbers, int numThreads) 
   {
      Map<Thread, Calculator> map = new HashMap<Thread, Calculator>();

      for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
      {
         final Calculator c = new Calculator(numbers, i, numThreads);

         Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               c.calculate();
            }
         });

         map.put(t, c);
         t.start();
      }

      for (Thread t : map.keySet())
      {
         try {
            t.join();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

      double total = 0;
      for (Calculator c : map.values())
         total += c.total;

      return total;
   }

   private static class Calculator
   {
      private final double[] numbers;
      private final int start;
      private final int step;
      private volatile double total;

      public Calculator(double[] numbers, int start, int step)
      {
         this.numbers = numbers;
         this.start = start;
         this.step = step;
      }

      void calculate()
      {
         double myTotal = 0;
         int myStep = step;
         for (int i = start; i < numbers.length; i += myStep)
            myTotal += numbers[i];

         total = myTotal;
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Running aggregation of 50000000 times 100 iterations...
> Threads: 1,  Time: 6.6146s,  Total: 2500279036.887666 
> Threads: 2,  Time: 4.1568s,  Total: 2500279036.888092 
> Threads: 3,  Time: 3.7190s,  Total: 2500279036.887598 
> Threads: 4,  Time: 3.5688s,  Total: 2500279036.887534 
> Threads: 5,  Time: 3.5660s,  Total: 2500279036.887787 
> Threads: 6,  Time: 4.0408s,  Total: 2500279036.887868 
> Threads: 7,  Time: 4.3832s,  Total: 2500279036.887928 
> Threads: 8,  Time: 4.4459s,  Total: 2500279036.887951 
> Threads: 9,  Time: 4.6616s,  Total: 2500279036.887927 
> Threads: 10,  Time: 4.1727s,  Total: 2500279036.887934 
> Threads: 11,  Time: 4.5164s,  Total: 2500279036.887979 
> Threads: 12,  Time: 5.4117s,  Total: 2500279036.887936 
> Threads: 13,  Time: 6.8391s,  Total: 2500279036.887914 
> Threads: 14,  Time: 7.1266s,  Total: 2500279036.887913 
> Threads: 15,  Time: 7.6294s,  Total: 2500279036.887928 
> Threads: 16,  Time: 7.3882s,  Total: 2500279036.887915 
> Threads: 17,  Time: 7.7739s,  Total: 2500279036.887911 
> Threads: 18,  Time: 7.7469s,  Total: 2500279036.887903 
> Threads: 19,  Time: 8.6564s,  Total: 2500279036.887903 
> Threads: 20,  Time: 9.2766s,  Total: 2500279036.887903 
> Done
> ```

Comment: 5 cores for java, 1 core for the OS / IDE.

Comment: @Pimgd In general, fine, but my box is completely idle otherwise. When my program is not running, CPU utilization shows 0-1% pretty consistently.

Comment: And don't forget you have 1 thread whose responsibility is making other threads.

Comment: @MrCodeMnky You're not taking into account context switching. For something computationally heavy like this, hyper-threading has no benefit, as it cannot actually process two instructions at a time on the same "core."

Comment: @EBrown I agree that beyond a certain point the context switching will cause performance to degrade significantly.  But I would still expect a near-linear speedup up to 6 cores. Perhaps there is something wrong with the code itself that is causing an unnecessary bottleneck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `volatile` on your `total` of the Calculator, but you don't actually read from it until the thread has finished. You could remove it, that way the synchronization on the variable would be removed.

---

Since one of your threads is responsible for starting new threads, that can be the first thread, saving you 1 more thread:

```
  for (int i = 1; i < numThreads; i++)
  {
     final Calculator c = new Calculator(numbers, i, numThreads);

     Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           c.calculate();
        }
     });

     map.put(t, c);
     t.start();
  }
  final Calculator c = new Calculator(numbers, 0, numThreads);
  c.calculate();

  double total = c.total;
  ...
```

That saves you an extra idle thread. You can only use this in example code like yours though, as real tasks will probably be better off with having a division between "worker threads" and "manager threads".

On that note, maybe you should use a thread pool of sorts - get the overhead of creating threads down.

```
  void calculate()
  {
     double myTotal = 0;
     int myStep = step;
     for (int i = start; i < numbers.length; i += myStep)
        myTotal += numbers[i];

     total = myTotal;
  }
```

Here you load `step` and `total` into a local for some reason, but not `numbers.length`. Why not?

Comment: Appreciate the comments! The one suggestion that improved performance was removing volatile from total on the Calculator. Made things faster about by 5%.

Comment: "ThreadPool of sorts" ForkJoinPool comes to mind

Answer (score 5):

## Bad order for cache

Your calculation routine is adding up every `n`th number, where `n` is the number of threads.  This is very bad for cache utilization.  If you split the list so that each thread had a contiguous chunk instead, that would be a lot better for cache utilization and make everything faster.

## Modified code

I made the following changes to your code:

First, I modified your `Calculator` class to take a `start` and `end` argument instead of a `start` and `step` argument:

```
private static class Calculator
{
    private final double[] numbers;
    private final int start;
    private final int end;
    private double total;

    public Calculator(double[] numbers, int start, int end)
    {
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    void calculate()
    {
        double myTotal = 0;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            myTotal += numbers[i];

        total = myTotal;
    }
}
```

Then I modified the `computeTotal()` function to split the numbers into evenly sized contiguous chunks:

```
private static double computeTotal(double[] numbers, int numThreads)
{
    Map<Thread, Calculator> map = new HashMap<Thread, Calculator>();
    int chunkSize = (numbers.length / numThreads);

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {
        int start = i * chunkSize;
        int end   = (i == numThreads - 1) ? numbers.length :
                                            (i+1) * chunkSize;
        final Calculator c = new Calculator(numbers, start, end);
```

## The results

These are the results on my machine before the change (4 cores, no hyperthreads, only 10 million doubles instead of 50 million):

```
Running aggregation of 10000000 times 100 iterations...
Threads: 1,  Time: 1.2901s,  Total: 499890086.941070
Threads: 2,  Time: 0.7689s,  Total: 499890086.941129
Threads: 3,  Time: 0.6693s,  Total: 499890086.941116
Threads: 4,  Time: 0.6586s,  Total: 499890086.941095
Threads: 5,  Time: 1.1863s,  Total: 499890086.941099
Threads: 6,  Time: 1.1560s,  Total: 499890086.941105
Threads: 7,  Time: 1.1590s,  Total: 499890086.941105
Threads: 8,  Time: 1.1804s,  Total: 499890086.941100
Threads: 9,  Time: 1.6860s,  Total: 499890086.941106
Threads: 10,  Time: 1.7471s,  Total: 499890086.941105
```

And these are the results after the cache friendly modifications:

```
Running aggregation of 10000000 times 100 iterations...
Threads: 1,  Time: 1.2738s,  Total: 499890086.941070
Threads: 2,  Time: 0.6965s,  Total: 499890086.941110
Threads: 3,  Time: 0.4985s,  Total: 499890086.941099
Threads: 4,  Time: 0.4814s,  Total: 499890086.941099
Threads: 5,  Time: 0.6425s,  Total: 499890086.941099
Threads: 6,  Time: 0.5468s,  Total: 499890086.941105
Threads: 7,  Time: 0.5108s,  Total: 499890086.941106
Threads: 8,  Time: 0.5244s,  Total: 499890086.941099
Threads: 9,  Time: 0.5870s,  Total: 499890086.941105
Threads: 10,  Time: 0.5293s,  Total: 499890086.941099
```